# Increase performance of HTML canvas animation

Tags: html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to animate multiple horizontal lines on a canvas like so:

```
var from = 0;

function draw()  {

  var to = from + step; 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

  for(var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {

    ctx.moveTo(from, data[row][from] + offset);

    for (var x = from + 1; x <= to; x++) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, data[row][x] + offset);
    }
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  from = to;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
}
```

It starts quite smoothly but becomes very slow in the end (especially on higher resolutions). Is there a better way to do an animation like that?

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/toruba/edit?js,output)

Comment: Remember to use `beginPath()` at some point ([example](https://jsbin.com/kotoyevovo/2/edit?js,output))

Comment: That's it, thank you!